# How to update the collection of @onetomany relationship

Tags: hibernate, gwt, requestfactory

I have the following code:

```
public class Parent{
   @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent",
        targetEntity= Child.class,
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        cascade= CascadeType.ALL,
        orphanRemoval=true)
   List<Child> children;
}

public class Child{
   @ManyToOne(
        targetEntity=Cotizacion.class,
        optional=false,
        fetch=FetchType.LAZY
        )
   @JoinColumn(
        name = "ID_PARENT",
        nullable = false
        ) 
   private Parent parent;   
}
```

Now in the client side i'm using GWT editor framework to edit the whole parent object, i mean.

```
Editor<ParentProxy>
ListEditor<List<ChildProxy>>
```

I have the requirement to edit the whole object on the same editor, so if i update a Child from the Parent and then flush() the driver the changes are propagated correctly.

The problem. On the server side i get the Parent with the children collection as persistedbag as null. (the Locator find() method is called for every Children). So if i do a change in the client side that is not propagated to the server side into the data base.

Note 1.- I check the whole object on the client side and the changes were made by the editor driver.

Note 2.- I tryed to retreive the whole object on the find() method of the Locator and doesn't work.

Note 3.- If i send the list as other parameter in my RequestContext and then update every child on the server side (DAO) it updates them correctly.

**UPDATE:** if i add a null to the children i get the whole list on server side instead of the persistedbag and the the update on the Child ocurrs.

Ex. parent.getChilds().add(null);

How  RequestFactory makes the delta changes on the entities?

Any help would be apreciated.

**UPDATE 2:**solution of thomas.

The classes (listeners):

```
 public class HibernateUtil implements ServletContextListener {}
 public class AppSessionManager implements Filter {}
```

The line that hibernate needs:

```
 <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
```

The web.xml config:

```
 <!-- Servlet context listerner  -->
<listener>
  <listener-class>xxx.yyy.server.tools.HibernateUtil</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Servlet for filter -->
<filter>  
    <filter-name>HibernateFilter</filter-name>  
    <filter-class>xxx.yyy.server.tools.AppSessionManager</filter-class>  
</filter>  

<filter-mapping>  
    <filter-name>HibernateFilter</filter-name>  
    <url-pattern>/gwtRequest</url-pattern>  
</filter-mapping>
```

the entity locator:

```
public class BaseEntityLocator extends Locator<BaseEntity, Integer> {
/* 
 * Method to fetch an object and merge the updates
 * 
 * @see com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.Locator#find(java.lang.Class, java.lang.Object)
 */
@Override
public BaseEntity find(Class<? extends BaseEntity> clazz, Integer id) {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();

    try {

        BaseEntity baseEntity = (BaseEntity) session.get(clazz, id);

        return baseEntity;
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {

        throw e;
    } 
 }
     ...
  }
```

Result? no more LazyInitializationException and other problems updating relations of type one to many. Hope this helps some one else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you're changing a `Child` but don't touch the `Parent` (at least not its `children` property). RequestFactory will then send a diff for that `Child` only, and only send the IDs of the `Parent` and the other edited `Child` objects.

On the server-side, each received entity is loaded using its `Locator`, and then the diffs are applied. RequestFactory doesn't nothing re. the relations, so the `Child` that gets loaded by the `Locator` **must** be the same instance as the `Child` that gets loaded by the `Parent` `Locator` in its `children` property.

To achieve that, it's generally only necessary to use the *session-per-request* pattern (aka *open session in view*):

- use a single session for the whole HTTP request to guarantee that the same entity will be the same Java instance
- but use one transaction per service method (you shouldn't need a transaction in your locators) to guarantee that `onSuccess` on the client-side is meaningful.

Comment: Yes, thanks thomas. The session-per-request solve the problem and improve our data access layer. This should be a recomendation in the RF documentation, i will post how to implement this in GWT since i dind't find any how to.

Comment: Feel free to send in patches to the doc: http://www.gwtproject.org/makinggwtbetter.html#webpage See also https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7341